# Dynamic table columns with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a table with 2 dynamic columns using one MySQL query. I was able to make the first row of columns but the second row is just blank. Any ideas? Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$query_dates ="SELECT uploadedby, count(item) as item, date_format(uploaddate, '%m-%d-%y') as date FROM `imsexport` WHERE uploadedby='Gerry Dellosa' and uploaddate between '2012-12-25' and '2013-01-15' GROUP BY date ORDER BY uploaddate ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query_dates,$prepress) or die(mysql_error());
$row_dates = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
<?php do{?>
    <td><?php echo $row_dates['date']?></td>
<?php } while ($row_dates = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
 </tr>
 <tr>//This is the second row set of dynamic columns
   <?php do{?>
    <td><?php echo $row_dates['date']?></td>
   <?php } while ($row_dates = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>  
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After the first do while loop you have iterated over the entire result set so the second so while loop contains nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you want 2 equal columns? or you just want to show your data in 2 columns?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: sorry that was a typo. second set of columns are actually for $row_dates['item'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$query_dates ="SELECT uploadedby, count(item) as item, date_format(uploaddate, '%m-%d-%y') as date FROM `imsexport` WHERE uploadedby='Gerry Dellosa' and uploaddate between '2012-12-25' and '2013-01-15' GROUP BY date ORDER BY uploaddate ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query_dates,$prepress) or die(mysql_error());
while($row_dates = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $record[] = $row_dates;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
<?php foreach($record as $rec ) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $rec['date'] ?></td>
<?php } ?>
 </tr>
 <tr>//This is the second row set of dynamic columns
   <?php foreach($record as $rec ) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $rec['date'] ?></td>
   <?php } ?>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks. Now what if there is no WHERE uploadedby='Gerry Dellosa' condition and I want uploadedby to echo vertically under the Name column while retaining the horizontal data values for each of the uploadedby values.

Comment: set the foreach for the line, not column, like `<table> <tr>..<td>name</td> <td>date</td>..</tr> .. foreach( .. ) { <tr>..<td>$rec[name]</td> <td>$rec[date]</td>..</tr> }`

Answer (score -1):

reset fetch loop before second row

```
mysql_data_seek($result,0);
```